# Como escrever Query utilizando Laravel

Tags: laravel

Como escrever essa Query no Laravel?

```
SELECT
        a.id, a.name, a.email, a.role, a.percentage, a.remaining_tax, a.min_peoples_per_table ,a.regions,
        GROUP_CONCAT( r.name SEPARATOR ", ") as regions_name
    FROM administrator as a
    INNER JOIN regions as r
        ON a.regions REGEXP CONCAT("[[:<:]]", r.id, "[[:>:]]")
    GROUP BY a.id
    ORDER BY a.id desc;
```

Código em construção:

```
$list = DB::table('administrator as a')
        ->select("a.id" , "a.name", "a.email", "a.role", "a.percentage", "a.remaining_tax", "a.min_peoples_per_table" ,"a.regions")
        ->groupBy("a.id")
        ->orderBy("a.id", "desc")
        ->get();
 return $list;
```

Na parte do GROUP_CONCAT e JOIN que estou meio perdido.

Comment: Editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

O método [`join()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins) aceita 4 argumentos:

1. A tabela que vai ser feito o join. Neste caso: `regions as r`.
2. O campo da cláusula `ON`. Neste caso: `a.regions`
3. O operador da cláusula `ON`. Neste caso: `REGEXP`
4. O segundo campo da cláusula `ON`. Neste caso nós podemos usar `DB::raw()` para adicionar o código. Ex.: `DB::raw('CONCAT("[[:<:]]", r.id, "[[:>:]]")')`

Então ficaria assim:

```php
<?php

$list = DB::table('administrator as a')
            ->select("*")
            ->join(
                'regions as r',
                'a.regions',
                'REGEXP',
                DB::raw('CONCAT("[[:<:]]", r.id, "[[:>:]]")')
            )
            ->groupBy("a.id")
            ->orderBy("a.id", "desc")
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::onRaw()
Deu esse erro.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Eu tinha confundido o `whereRaw` e acabei complicando mais do que o necessário. Acredito que agora vai dar certo.